# Stopping a service when receive Low Battery broadcast

Tags: android, service, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver

I want to stop a service if the emulator goes in low battery status. So I added a receiver in the manifest file (i.e. *AndroidManifest.xml*) and created a BrodcastReciver subclass in my activity.

When I'm trying to change the battery level for the emulator the battery level changes but the service doesn't stop. I have no idea why this occurs.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```java
package reemaljunaid.myexample;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent music = new Intent();
        music.setClass(this,MusicService.class);
        startService(music);
    }

    static public class BatteryLevelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Low battry recived","True");
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, MusicService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="reemaljunaid.myexample">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$BatteryLevelReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="MusicService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:stopWithTask="true"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MusicService.java

```java
package reemaljunaid.myexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Reem on 1/6/2017.
 */

public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        }
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
                    extra) {
                onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        mPlayer.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```